# How to disable Auto Complete in Sublime Text (2&3)

Tags: html, css, text, autocomplete, sublimetext

[image]
I understand there are a few questions surrounding the auto_complete function in Sublime Text.

However, I have not been able to disable the auto_complete function in the Sublime Text settings (I've tried both Sublime Text 2&3). I just get the `"Error trying to parse settings: Unexpected trailing characters in Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings:5:1"` error when inputting the `{"auto_complete": false,}` command in **user settings**.

Would love to turn off the setting, but can't find a way to. Any help much appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Why did you put the settings in two separate sets of curly braces, as opposed to the original settings which had them comma-delimited in one? And if you have them in one set, make sure they actually are delimited by commas.

Answer (score 9):

Put `,` after `font-size:17` like:

```
{
  "font_size":17, //note a comma here after 17
  "auto_complete": false,    
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There are two options:

1:  In Preference --> User,  Check if `TernJS plugin` is Installed. If Yes, Unistall it from your editor (i.e. Sublime Text Editor).

2: In Preferences --> User, check for the `auto_complete` and change it to false

> "auto_complete": false,

Restart Your Editor(Sublime Text)

Answer (score 5):

This is the first result that pops up when Googling "Sublime Text disable autocomplete", and none of the answers answered my question completely, so I'd just like to add to the existing answers that if you are setting auto_complete to false and still having problems with Sublime Text auto-closing parentheses and brackets, then you also need to set auto_match_enabled to false.  This should solve the problem.  So as a whole, here is what I have:

```
{
    "auto_complete": false,
    "auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false,
    "auto_close_tags":false,
    "auto_match_enabled": false
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer -- finally (all of them must be put onto the Preferences > Settings > User)

Answer (score 2):

This should be the option.

```
{
    "auto_close_tags":false
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: This should be the answer for anyone trying to disable the tag autocomplete for HTML/XML specifically

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this problem was to change "auto_complete_commit_on_tab" from true 
to false. This way you aren't turning off autocomplete altogether, but the autocompletion is ignored unless you hit the tab key.

In preferences, user settings, add:

```
{
"auto_complete_commit_on_tab": false
}
```

Comment: Do you mean setting it to true? This is what prevented forced errors while typing for me. It also gives you a list with the most relevant suggestion on top. Recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a Python-related solution, where autocompletion worked well for variable names etc. but was quite slow for methods etc.

So, to disable Python syntax autocomplete:

- open the command palette with ctrl + shift + P
- enter *Package Control: Remove Package* and select it
- enter *Jedi* and remove the *Jedi autocomplete* package