# Disable autocomplete on Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

I am trying to disable or remove the 

[autocomplete](https://gyazo.com/9a66513210ff5d88077de80d9edd548a)
feature in Sublime Text 3.
I did try to disable it by:

`"auto_complete": false`

in settings but this didn't work.
Please Help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list is comma separated. Make sure to put a comma after any preceding items.

```
{
    "font_size":17,
    "auto_complete": false
}
```

Make sure you restart the application afterwards.

**Here is an unofficial [doc](https://www.granneman.com/webdev/editors/sublime-text/configuring-sublime-text) which states the following:**

> Note that if you choose to add anything to your personal settings file, the following rules apply:
>
> -The last preference must not have a comma after it
>
> -All other preferences must have commas after them
>
> Failure to adhere to these rules will result in your personal settings file not working!

Comment: Just as a note, the Sublime JSON parser isn't as strict as standard JSON parsers; it tolerates comments as well as trailing commas where other JSON parsers throw errors.

Comment: Any luck here? If you were able to find an answer on your own please post it and give the green check mark.

Answer (score -1):

Preferences ▶ Settings:

"auto_complete": false

[How to disable Auto Complete in Sublime Text (2&3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41903584/how-to-disable-auto-complete-in-sublime-text-23)